# Axios Interceptors not sending cookie despite withCredentials is true. Silent Refresh JWT with Azure Functions API

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, axios, azure-functions

How to send cookie with Axios interceptors, even if withCredentials is set to true?

Error: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Code:

I have a dummy function that sends a username and password to a serverless API with Azure Functions and NodeJS.

```
    try {
      const data = await api.get("/api/getUser")
      return data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

The API is an axios config which sets the headers and withCredentials. It connects the interceptors for silent refresh with refresh tokens.

```
const api = setupInterceptorsTo(
  axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:7071",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "localhost",
    },
    // withCredentials: true, <-- Uncommenting this causes the problem. 
  })
)
```

The interceptors look like this

```
// onResponse, onRequest, onRequest are omitted here.

const onResponseError = async (error: AxiosError): Promise<AxiosError> => {
  if (error.response) {

    // Access Token was expired
    if (error.response.status === 403) {
      try {
        const rs = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:7071/api/refreshAccessToken`)

        // Gets new access token
        const { token } = rs.data.accessToken

        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token))
      } catch (_error) {
        return Promise.reject(_error)
      }
    }
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
}

export const setupInterceptorsTo = (
  axiosInstance: AxiosInstance
): AxiosInstance => {
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(onRequest, onRequestError)
  axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(onResponse, onResponseError)
  return axiosInstance
}
```

The error no matter what I do comes from uncommenting withCredentials: true in either the axios.create function OR by adding it to the get request to send the refresh token cookie to the backend.

Inspecting the network requests says the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set to * despite setting it within the axios.create function.

The cookie returned from /login route is in the set-cookie header.

```
cookies: [
        {
          name: "jid",
          value: refreshToken,
          maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 7 days
          httpOnly: true,
        },
      ],
```

I am out of ideas after trying to fix this for many hours. Advice appreciated.

Comment: Does the server send a single host in access-control-allow-origin as the error states it MUST. i.e. the issue is with the server code

Comment: It was a server problem. Despite setting CORS in local.settings.json to localhost, it would still send the access-control-allow-origin as *, and to fix it every time I run the functions I have to force it by func host start --cors http://localhost:3000.